# How to write range query in elastic search 8.8.0

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a problem to write **range query** for **elastic search** running on **Docker** in my **Spring Boot** example.

I tried to write **RangeQuery** but I cannot implement it in `elasticsearchClient.search.`

How can I do that?

Here is the code snippet shown below

```
public List<Item> searchItemsByPriceRange(double minPrice, double maxPrice) throws IOException {
        RangeQuery rangeQuery = new RangeQuery.Builder()
                .field("price")  // Specify the field name here
                .gte(JsonData.of(minPrice))   // Greater than or equal to minPrice
                 .lte(JsonData.of(maxPrice))   // Less than or equal to maxPrice
                .build();

        log.info("Elasticsearch query: {}", rangeQuery.toString());

        SearchResponse<Item> response = elasticsearchClient.search(q ->
                q.index("itemindex").query(rangeQuery), Item.class);

        log.info("Elasticsearch response: {}", response.toString());

        return extractItemsFromResponse(response);
}


private List<Item> extractItemsFromResponse(SearchResponse<Item> response) {
    return response
            .hits()
            .hits()
            .stream()
            .map(Hit::source)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here is the problem part

```
SearchResponse<Item> response = elasticsearchClient.search(q ->
                q.index("itemindex").query(rangeQuery), Item.class);

Cannot resolve method 'query(RangeQuery)'
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I shared it.

Comment: What version of SDE are you using?

Comment: @Val What is SDE?

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch

Comment: @Val The version is 3.1.4

Comment: SDE version is not relevant here, this is a Elasticsearch Java Client question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the use a `Query.Builder` in the `query()` method and on this you can set the `rangeQuery`

```
SearchResponse<Item> response = elasticsearchClient.search(q -> q
  .index("itemindex")
  .query(queryBuilder -> queryBuilder.range(rangeQuery))
  ), Item.class);
```